# Joomla mobile template testing

Tags: joomla

Joomla automagically recognises the mobile template and displays it on the mobile devices. but sometimes it does not display(very rarely) and also sometimes the behaviour is different(like logo disappearing).

Question:
1) Is there a way we can test the mobile template on the desktop computers (like m.mobilesite.com) so that we can debug the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes You can,

The http://www.browserstack.com sites Provide a real machine for testing the device and browser compactability.(It a remote machine so the result is 100%).This required signup.

Also you can check iphone and ipad compactabilty with safari Developer option.

```
From Settings->Preference ->Advanced ->check the Show Develop menu option.
```

Now you will get a new menu in the browser Developer there you can choose the user agent.

You can also find several sites that provide mobile testing but those are not 100% sure
like iphone4simulator.com, iphonetester.com

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

I also found that - If you decrease your browser width and height - it will display mobile format. I am not sure if this is a feature of later versions of joomla. Also on Chrome - developer tools, there is an option to choose the mobile device to test the webpage. [image]